# Using Array.prototype.includes to target property in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

With `Array.prototype.includes` you can do something like this:

```
let array1 = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(array1.includes(2)); // return true
```

My question is: can you use `includes` for an array of objects, where you want to find, say,  "name" = "Jane"? Take for instance the following data:

`let array2 = [{"name" : "John", age: 24}, {"name" : "Jane", age: 36}]`

Is this something you can do with the `includes` method - and what would it look like?

Comment: Can only use `includes(object)` if the object references were the same

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You *can* use it, but only if you have the reference to the object (*not* its structural equivalent).

```
const o1 = { name: '1' }
const o2 = { name: '2' }
const arr = [o1, o2]
arr.includes(o1) // true
arr.includes({ name: '1' }) // false
```

This is because `includes` uses the "SameValueZero" algorithm, [as per the spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.includes) (emphasis mine):

> `includes` compares `searchElement` to the elements of the array, in ascending order, **using the SameValueZero algorithm**, and if found at any position, returns `true`; otherwise, `false` is returned.

"[SameValueZero](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-samevaluezero)" will always return false for different references, hence the second attempt from the code above will return `false`.

You can use `Array#some` instead, which lets you specify a lambda as the parameter. Then you can write your custom equality logic even for objects.

```
arr.some(o => o.name == '1') // true
```

From [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53562783/using-array-prototype-includes-to-target-property-in-an-array-of-objects/53562864#comment93991329_53562810), I see you're interested in checking against multiple values. You can simply use the `||` operator with `some` in this case:

```
arr.some(o => o.name == '1' || o.name == '2' || o.name == '3')
```

If you do not wish to specify all of them like this, you can do something like the following.

```
arr.some(o => ['1', '2', '3'].includes(o.name))
```

Answer (score 3):

In that case you could use `some` method instead and it will return `true` on first match.

```js
let array = [{"name" : "John", age: 24}, {"name" : "Jane", age: 36}]
let check = array.some(({name}) => name == 'Jane');
console.log(check)
```

Comment: Thanks, good to know. Follow up question, what about if you wanted to check against an array of values, rather than just one?

Comment: Give me an example.

Comment: Okay, say where you want to check for both "Jane" and "John" with one query.

Comment: @Ademo use a nested `some` or `includes`: `array.some({name} => values.includes(name))` Which reads: check if _some_ object in `array` has its `name` _included_ in the array `values`.

Comment: @Ademo See my answer here for your case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53562864/2131286

Comment: @Ademo Then you could use `every` on array of names and inside `some` method like this https://jsfiddle.net/sfu9kt5h/59/

Answer (score 2):

```
  array.find(user => user.name === "Jane")
```

As objects get compared by reference, `.includes` doesn't help you in most cases, then you have to through all elements manually and check for equality, thats what `.find` does. It either returns the found user or `undefined`. If you just need a boolean use `.some` that works like `.find` but either returns true or false.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```js
let array2 = [{
  "name": "John",
  age: 24
}, {
  "name": "Jane",
  age: 36
}]

var some = array2.some((i) => {
  return i.name === 'Jane'
})

var map = array2.map((i) => {
  return i.name === 'Jane'
})

console.log('some', some)
console.log('map', map)
```